# How to generate a list of sets of inequalities in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to do the following in Mma. Suppose I have three expressions, `x1, 3 x1-x2, x2-x1` where `0<=x1,x2<=1`). I want to have another one which specifies the largest among the three is at least twice of the smallest. So there are some permutation of the three in terms of their order:

```
x1<=3 x1-x2<=x2-x1 && 2 x1<=x2-x1
3 x1-x2<=x1<=x2-x1 && 2 (3 x1-x2)<=x2-x1
```

....
with the rest 4 similar conditions.

How do I form these conditions automatically (together with `0<=x1,x2<=1`), and then feed them into Reduce one-by-one, and solve for x2 in terms of x1?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
eqs = {x1, 3 x1 - x2, x2 - x1};
Reduce[Max[eqs] >= 2 Min[eqs], {x1, x2}, Reals]
```

If you want to do comparisons with second-largest or third largest/smallest then can use `RankedMax`

As far as solving it for x2 -- there are many different values of `x2` corresponding to each `x1` so you can't solve it in the conventional sense, you can see it from `RegionPlot`

```
RegionPlot[Max[eqs] >= 2 Min[eqs], {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

Comment: @Yaroslav Bulatov: in version <8.0, how to get equivalent expression for RankedMax? Sort and then extract the element does not seem to work. Many thanks again!

Comment: sorry, don't have access to mathematica 7.0 atm so I can't test it

Comment: @Yaroslav Bulatov: Any other suggestions you may have please?

Comment: Without RankedMax you need to specify the possibilities explicitly. For instance, if you want to say that second largest out of a,b,c is above 2, you could say "(b<a<c||c<a<b)&&a>2||(c<b<a||a<b<c)&&b>2||(a<c<b||b<c<a)&&c>2". You may get quite a large number of equations this way, don't know an efficient way to do it, sorry

Comment: @Yaroslav Bulatov: is there any way in Mma 7.0 to write one's own function which is equivalent to RankedMax in Mma 8.0?

Comment: probably, but I haven't thought about it, and I don't have mma 7.0

Answer (score 0):

Use `Max` and `Min` and specify `x2` before `x1` in the variable list, as follows

```
In[1]:= Reduce[
         Max[x1, 3 x1 - x2, x2 - x1] >= 2 Min[x1, 3 x1 - x2, x2 - x1] && 
         0 <= x1 && x2 <= 1, 
         {x2, x1}]
```